# What would be the logic to make a ball move within concentric circle using accelerometer in cocos2d

Tags: ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I want to know the best approach to make a sprite ball move within concentric circle using accelerometer in cocos2d. Ive used the equation of the circle to see if the sprite lies within the circle or not.

Answer (score 0):

Find next position of your sprite according to accelerometer input, check if it lies within your area, if yes, update sprite's position.

Comment: How do i get to know the next position of my sprite. I am using an accelerometer to move my sprite.

Comment: Either you already use accelerometer to move sprite or you have no idea how to figure sprite's next position with accelerometer. Pick one.

Comment: then why do you ask how to get it?